# How to make Jade stop HTML encoding element attributes, and produce a literal string value?

Tags: templates, underscore.js, pug, html-encode, string-literals

**UPDATE** Jade v0.24.0 fixes this with a `!=` syntax for attributes. `option(value!='<%= id %>')`

---

I'm trying to build an `<option>` with jade, where the value of the option is an UnderscoreJS template marker: `<%= id %>` but I can't get it to work because jade is converting my marker text to `&lt;= id &gt;`.

Here's my Jade markup:

```js
script(id="my-template", type="text/template")
  select(id="type")
    &lt;% _.each(deviceTypes, function(type){ %>
    option(value='&lt;%= type.id %>') <%= type.name %>
    &lt;% }) %>
```

I expect it to produce this html:

```html
<script id="my-template" type="text/template">
  <select id='type'>
    <% _.each(deviceTypes, function(type){ %>
    <option value="<%= type.id %>"> <%= type.name %> </option>
    <% }) %>
  </select>
</script>
```

But what I get instead, is this:

```html
<script id="my-template" type="text/template">
  <select id='type'>
    <% _.each(deviceTypes, function(type){ %>
    <option value="&lt;%= type.id %&gt;"> <%= type.name %> </option>
    <% }) %>
  </select>
</script>
```

Note the very subtle difference in the `<option>` line of the output... the `value` attribute of the option has been HTML encoded.

How do I prevent Jade from HTML encoding this value? I need it to produce the literal value, the same way it does with the text of the option.

Comment: I've recently had the same issue with setting attribute values using Underscore and found a work around.  Not super-pretty, but it's better than using raw HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of this writing I don't believe there's a way to it. See this issue:
https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/198

I ended up dropping into raw HTML to solve it, using the | prefix.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Dropping back to | got it working for now ... life on the bleeding edge... :P

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, see Minime's answer.

Answer (score 103):

Derick has already mentioned that Jade added new feature for unescape HTML encoding in update, but I'd like to add some addendum for someone who might not recognize.

```
- var html = "<script></script>"
| !{html} <-- Escaped
| #{html} <-- Encoded
```

from https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

Comment: (! && Minime) made my day :)

Comment: According to http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/ !{html} is unescaped and #{html} does convert entities

Comment: This is life saving.

Answer (score 35):

This feature has been [added to Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/commit/89b67964be0c28fbb669d3953ef132f22de07a72). You simply use the `!=` operator if you want to unescape attribute values:

```
script#my-template(type='text/template')
  a(href!='<%= url =>') Clicky clicky...
```

Comment: This works! Doesn't seem to work for class attributes, though.

Comment: @cgenco it should, provided your version of jade > 1.9.2

Comment: I know - [I fixed it](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1087#issuecomment-20779899) ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I was having an issue similar to this, where I wanted to create an Underscore template inside one of my Jade views.  A piece of the Underscore template needed to set the `selected` attribute in an `<option>` tag.

Initially I tried having Underscore return "selected" or "".  Unfortunately, [Jade doesn't have a way to display an attribute with no value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020142/jade-element-attributes-without-value) and doesn't have a way of non-escaping attribute names (the Underscore bits were coming back without quotation marks).

Luckily, you are able to unescape the *value* of an attribute, preserving the quotation marks.

In this example, I'm selecting a value of a dropdown based on the owner type matching a string value.  I set a helper function so I wouldn't have to manually escape quotation marks.

```
- var checkType = function(type) { return "<%= contact.type == '" + type + "' %>" };

.clearfix
  label Title:
  .input
    select(type="text", name="contact[title]", class="new-title")
      option(value="") Choose Title
      option(value="manager", selected="#{ checkType('manager') }") Manager
      option(value="member", selected="#{ checkType('member') }") Member
      option(value="owner", selected="#{ checkType('owner') }") Owner
      option(value="president", selected="#{ checkType('president') }") President
      option(value="individual", selected="#{ checkType('individual') }") Individual
      option(value="main_contact", selected="#{ checkType('main_contact') }") Main Contact
```

According to some, you should be able to use `!{}` here to completely avoid all encoding (`<, >, etc.`), however this did not work on my version of Jade.  I'm using `"^0.30"` and the current version is `1.x`.

If someone can verify that `!{}` does work in this situation using the latest version of Jade, I'll update my answer.

Comment: `!{}` works in pug (jade's new name) in v2.0.0-alpha8