# Jade: element attributes without value

Tags: attributes, pug

I am new to using Jade -- and it's awesome so far.

But one thing that I need to happen is an element with 'itemscope' property:

```
<header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
```

My Jade notation is:

```
header(itemscope, itemtype='http://schema.org/WPHeader')
```

But result is:

```
<header itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
```

How can I make sure that I get the right result -- `itemscope` instead of `itemscope="itemscope"`?

Comment: itemscope="itemscope" will work just as well as just itemscope. It looks like that's the default behavior of Jade. I'd just go with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried it in a Express.js/Jade project and the result i get is:

```
<header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader"></header>
```

I also tried it in bash and then I get the same result as you.

I'd go with the following suggestion or create an issue on Github.

> itemscope="itemscope" will work just as well as just itemscope. It looks like that's the default behavior of Jade. I'd just go with it.

Comment: Thanks. Strange that result is different. Alright, will go with this.

Comment: This is still showing up in google searches. The correct solution for me was to set the attribute equal to the empty string.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes it doesn't work quite right -- like with `contentEditable` Jade tries to detect html5 doctypes and then does `<header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader"></header>` if it finds it. The problem is that if you have templates that you are inserting in the page, it can't tell that it's html5.

What you can do is force html5 compilation by passing in `{doctype: '5'}` to the options -- did this for require-jade: https://github.com/ibash/require-jade/commit/754cba2dce7574b400f75a05172ec97465a8a5eb

Comment: I believe the syntax is now `{doctype: 'html'}`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem using angular ng-include directive. It gets ng-include="ng-include" and then the include doesn'nt work.

What it works for me is to use an empty string as a value, i.e. ng-include="".

Comment: Yeah I've been spending some time trying to get jade play along but it was definitely not written with angular in mind

Answer (score 8):

Here is answer from jade developers: you should use

```
  doctype html
```

in the template.

https://github.com/pugjs/jade/issues/370

Comment: this comment should go on top of every `jade-template`.   After which we don't need to assign `blank-string` values to the attributes. `doctype html` and next line `div#core(ui-view controller="CoreCtrl")`.  Note the `ui-view` in the code.  Thanks @alehro

Comment: Yep, this was it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the easiest solution in my case was adding `doctype 5` at the top of my jade document. That apparently allows Jade to use attributes without a value.
ibash put me on the right track with his answer, so thanks for that

Comment: The compiler says that: doctype 5 is deprecated, use html instead. Thus, I just write doctype html just before html(lang=en). FYI.