# How to encode decoded-html in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, html-encode

I'm playing around with Node.js and have connected to my mysql-database and are fetching 
some blog-records, but the contents are decoded html in the db. I can't seem to encode.
I've tried it in the controller (i'm using express), and are trying it in the jade-view. 
Actually i have not a clue about best practices, but are anyway hacking through something.
Some help would be appreciated.

**In my index.jade:**

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');


extends layout
```

The problem lies somewhere with Jade (but where?):

From controller:

```
 res.render('index', { title: '<i>Express</i>', bloglist : rows });
```

The html tags is not showing correctly:

```
<i>Express</i>


block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

     div
      for blog in bloglist
        h3 #{blog.Title}
         p #{decoder.write(blog.Text)}
```

Comment: what does console.log(blog.Text) output?

Comment: I can't remember where I read about this, but I think you don't need to htmlencode/decode as jade (is awesome) it does all this for you. I will try to find this article for you, so bare with...

Comment: See if this question helps, as I can't seem to find that article ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111232/how-to-make-jade-stop-html-encoding-element-attributes-and-produce-a-literal-st