# How to prevent Jade Template parsing HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I am using Jade Template in conjunction with Angular JS and have such repeater processing simple array defined in angular's controller : $scope.ids = ['demo1', 'demo2']

```
.controls(ng-repeat="controlId in ids")
  <div id="{{$index}}">{{$index}}</div>
```

Whatever i do Jade tries to parse everything passed to the SELECT tag and thus it always removes $index variable from tag's attribute. As result in HTML i always see the following:

```
<div id="">0</div> // ID attribute is always empty because Jade replaces it
<div id="">1</div> // at the same time HTML of the tag was rendered correctly
```

**Question** : how to prevent parsing of this HTML attribute by Jade and print string as is in a result HTML?

P. S. I tried the following syntax and it does not work ... suggestions?

```
id="|{{$index}}" // id is empty
id!="{{$index}}" // id is empty
id="!{{$index}}" // syntax error
id="!{{controlId}}" // syntax error
{:id => {{$index}}} // does not add ID at all
```

P. P. S. Just to explain why i am messing up Jade with HTML - i tried to use "jade only" syntax and it also did not work :

```
.controls(ng-repeat="controlId in ids")
  .demo(id="{{$index}}") {{$index}}
```

Comment: There is no reason why it should not work. Why are you using .controls which is jade. and <div> which is html? probably your div has come out of the scope of .controls in html.

Comment: @Sangram Singh : i tried to use only Jade syntax until i realized that i simply need raw HTML this is why here i show two different kinds of syntax, briefly - "Jade only syntax" does not work too

Comment: The problem is not with Jade. I'm using id={{$index}} and it works. What is `ids = ?`

Comment: @Sangram Singh : replied above $scope.ids = ['demo1', 'demo2']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently i found this discussion started by Sangram :

[{{$index}} of ng-repeat computed after linker function of angular directive. $compile it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254705/index-of-ng-repeat-computed-after-linker-function-of-angular-directive-co)

And i realized that Sangram was right about this - this is not Jade issue - this is how angular renders templates.

There was a solution - to call linking function inside $evalAsync - probably it is a good alternative but in my case i need to set ID of the control immediately so i came up to this solution - if i cannot set the ID - i can generate it :

```
app.directive('tags', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    var controlIndex = 0;

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {

    // *** Control ID *** //

        element[0].id = attrs.id || 'control' + (++controlIndex);

        ...
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'tags/template.html',
        link: linker
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent the parsing like that :

```
!{{$index}} <-- Escaped
```

Refer to this post : [How to make Jade stop HTML encoding element attributes, and produce a literal string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111232/how-to-make-jade-stop-html-encoding-element-attributes-and-produce-a-literal-st)

And to this issue : https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/198

And say if it works !

Comment: yes, i saw these issues, unfortunately it does not work and i updated my answer to describe what happens when i use !{{$index}} or !{{controlId}}