# {{$index}} of ng-repeat computed after linker function of angular directive. $compile it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

html

```
<div repeater ng-repeat='item in items' class='first' id = '{{$index}}' > {{item}} </div>
```

angularjs directive:-

```
angular.module('time', [])
  .directive('repeater', function() {

    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs){
      var id = $(element).attr('id');
      alert(id); // {{$index}}
    } ...
```

dynamic id created inside ng-repeat, when evoked inside directive displays as {{$index}} instead of value = 0, 1, 2 ...

How do you ensure when Linker function in directive executes the dynamic ids are used?  I think it can be done using [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) inside the directive. But i can't quite figure how?

```
$compile(element)(scope)
```

is the syntax. But obviously the wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need the IDs to be already populated you can run the relevant code inside `scope.$evalAsync` or `$timeout` to make sure the binding has been updated first. I would suggest trying hard to avoid needing to inspect the DOM and relying instead on your model for any of this information, using `scope.$index`.

Your directive is already in the process of being compiled when and linked when your link function is reached so I think recompiling wouldn't help. It is just a case of waiting long enough to finish the linking and start a `$digest` where the attributes will actually be updated. This is exactly what `$evalAsync` will do for you.

Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/n77x4C?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

1. directive

   ```
    angular.module('time', []).directive('repeater', function() {
      return{
             restrict:"E",
             scope:{
                   itemarray: "=itemarray"
                }
             template:"<div ng-repeat='item in itemarray' class='first' id = '{{$index}}' > {{item}} </div>",
              link:linkFn
           }
             var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs){
            var id = $(element).attr('id');
            alert(id); // {{$index}}
   ```

   } ...
2. html

   ```
          <repeater itemarray='itemarray"></repeater>
   ```

Comment: this is pretty innovative but i'm afraid it doesn't work. The execution of the linker function takes place before {{item}} is computed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gf4tq/4/ watch the alert for the id, which contains {{$index}}.