# $compile dynamic id of element in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

For some reason the id in `<div class='popup' id = '{{$index}}'` is wrong inside its directive.

How can i manually [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) the id of an element?

```
.directive('repeater', function() {

var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs){
  var id = $(element).attr('id');
  alert(id);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [{{$index}} of ng-repeat computed after linker function of angular directive. $compile it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254705/index-of-ng-repeat-computed-after-linker-function-of-angular-directive-co)

Comment: I think you're getting the index of the element after it's been rendered if in the template you did {{$parent.$index}} I bet it would give you the right index