# calling an angularjs attribute directive from inside an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a collection of table column objects that I am iterating over using ng-repeat.  I am building the table dynamically based on the columns the user wants to see.

Each TH tag calls a "sortable" directive like this...

```
<th sortable collection="myCollection" sortcolumn="sortcolname">Heading</th>
```

this is fine when the values for the custom attributes are hard-coded in (as above).  But, in my code I am getting the values from the object in the collection like this....

```
<th ng-repeat="col in cols" sortable collection="{{col.collection}}" sortcolumn="{{col.sortcol}}">{{col.DisplayName}}</th>
```

This is not working.  The values in the custom attributes (collection & sortcolumn) have not been rendered in time and the sortable directive is getting the variable names ({{col.collection}} && {{col.sortcol}}) and not the variable values.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm very new to angular but I know you can set the priority of a directive. As a guess you could try changing the priority of the collection and sortcolumn directives to get processed after ng-repeat?

Comment: This did not seem to work -- I looked at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270392/what-is-priority-of-ng-repeat-directive-can-you-change-it and set it to 1001 and 999 and neither works.

Comment: try passing your values to `collection` and `sortcolumn` without using the {{}}, ex: `collection="col.collection"`

Comment: I think m.e.conroy has the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I've done any Angular, but are you sure you need the double brackets in your collection and sortcolumn attributes? As in, does this work?

```
<th ng-repeat="col in cols" sortable collection="col.collection" sortcolumn="col.sortcol">{{col.DisplayName}}</th>
```