# Loading directives sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface, angularjs-directive

I have an html view which is full of angular directives. The problem is that each directive performs a lot of http requests. This is causing heavy load on the CPU usage. Our idea was to load one directive at a time i.e. as one directive initializes its controller (and therefore performs the calls), the next one starts.

**EDIT:** The directives are in different DOM elements i.e. I can't use priorities or preLinks, etc..

Do you think this is even possible?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is \`priority\` of ng-repeat directive can you change it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270392/what-is-priority-of-ng-repeat-directive-can-you-change-it)

Comment: @Vineet maybe... but does this mean that if directive 1 has priority of 1001 and directive 2 has priority of 1002 that directive 2 has finished all of its calls before directive 1 is called?

Comment: Priority will work for single DOM element, I think in this case directive are on different DOM element, Is it right @Bernice?

Comment: yes I have multiple directives defined in different DOM elements.. So to use priority directives have to be in a parent-child hierarchy @KishorSharma?

Comment: just to clarify, I want a way for the user to use these directives as widgets. i.e. the user can have as many widgets as he wants in a page. But at the same time I need to monitor the flow of directives execution because of the large number of queries being executed (performance issues)

Comment: @Bernice. Oops then in your case above hint will not work.

Comment: @Bernice, You can have a widgetRequestService and each directive will use it to make request. In service,  you can stackup and process each request.

Comment: @KishorSharma could you please clarify your comment? Are you talking about some kind of lock / queue?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can have a WidgetRequestService, which can be used by widget to make http request. You directive can make request like:

```
widgetRequestService.makeCall(url, priority, function() {/*success call back*/}, function () {/*failcallBack*/})
```

And in your service you can have a queue (you can sort it based on priority after every call) and a method:

```
makeCall: function (url, priority, successCallback, failCallback) {
    //add url to queue
} 

processCall: function() {//to process url}
```

This way you widget will provide its priority set by user.