# JADE render angular scope var with HTML and JSON in

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs

I have a angualrjs var which is HTML with JSON, it basically read from the database.

The var is

```
    <div id='tes-34ncd' class='classname'><span class='classname-data' title='{"id":"34f3fgg","server":"www.example.com","geometry":{"width":470,"height":"infinite"},"configuration":{"newEntryLocation":"top","commentLocation":"top","replayContentOrder":"chronological","pinsGrowSize":"on","titlePage":"off","skinOverride":"117"}}'>&nbsp;</span></div>
```

Now if I just use {{ varname }} it shows the html with tags, it doesn't properly render it

I have tried with != and ! and = and no luck

My Nodejs server is:

```
    app.configure(function(){
      app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
      app.set('view engine', 'jade');
      app.set('view options', {
        layout: false
      });
      app.use( express.cookieParser() );

      app.use(express.favicon());
      app.use(express.json());
      app.use(express.urlencoded());
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
      app.use(app.router);
    });
```

Does anyone know how to render it properly?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but have you checked this possible duplicate out?

[How to make Jade stop HTML encoding element attributes, and produce a literal string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111232/how-to-make-jade-stop-html-encoding-element-attributes-and-produce-a-literal-st)